# Prevent final character from being a number

Tags: bash, random, alphanumeric, one-liner

In bash, I run the following to get a random string:

```
LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc 'a-z0-9' </dev/urandom | fold -w 5 | head -n1
```

However, I need to make sure the last character is not a number.

What can I add to the command to do this, keeping it as a one-liner?

*(I'd like it to be the same length, but if I have to trim it to 4 chars, so be it)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep` to select those lines that meet the criterion, and only then take the first one:

```
LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc 'a-z0-9' </dev/urandom | fold -w 5 | grep '[^0-9]$' | head -n1
```

By the way, `echo $(x)` is a nonsensical construct most of the time; you can just write `x` instead.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about `echo`, couldn't see the code from the bugs yesterday!